# JasperReports, Documento Não Contém Paginas?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, jasper, relatório

Olá, sou novato com JasperReports e estou enfrentando um problema para conseguir gerar meu primeiro relatório (um DANFE), tudo que vi sobre o jasper até aqui envolvia banco de dados, como minha aplicação não usa banco ignorei isso e estou tentando passar os dados via HashMap, tudo aparenta estar ok, a aplicação funciona perfeitamente, mas quando o relatório vai abrir recebo uma mensagem dizendo que o documento não possui páginas, jás testei outros layouts JRXML que que encontrei por ai, nenhum abre, segue o código que carrega o jasper.

```
private void loader(){
    try{

        JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("src/jasper/teste.jrxml");
        Map dados = new HashMap();
        dados.put("Emit_CNPJ", this.nfe.getEmitente().getCnpj());
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, dados);
        JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jp, false);
        jv.setTitle("DANFE");
        jv.setVisible(true);

        debug.log("DANFE carregada com sucesso.");
    }catch(JRException ex){
        debug.log("Falha ao carregar JasperReports.");
        //Logger.getLogger(Visualizer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: O seu arquivo teste.jrxml está com todos os parâmetros certinhos?

Answer (score 0):

Os dados que vc quer passar pro jasper, estão em um banco de dados? Analisando seu código, eu tenho um exemplo sobre passar parametros pro jasper, porem estes dados estão em um banco de dados, saca só:

```
JasperReport jasperR;
JasperPrint jasperP;
JRResultSetDataSource jrRS;
Map parametros;

rs=stmt.executeQuery("Select * from tabela");
/* implementação da interface JRDataSource para DataSource ResultSet */
jrRS = new JRResultSetDataSource( rs );// no caso, o rs seria o resultado da query.

parametros = new HashMap();
jasperR = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("report1.jrxml");
jasperP = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperR, parametros, jrRS);
```

Na última linha, tem 3 parâmetros, o report do jasper, o hash map como segundo, e o result set como ultimo parâmetro.
Espero ter te ajudado.

Comment: Fiz exatamente como no exemplo do @Thiago e não deu certo.. continua aparecendo documento não contem páginas..

Answer (score 0):

Olá, volto aqui para agradecer pelas respostas, felizmente já consegui resolver o problema, não sei se é correto mas por hora o relatório está sendo exibido, ao que tudo indica o jasper não exibe o relatório sem um "DataSource", por isso na linha:

```
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, dados);
```

adicionei um BeanCollection passando um arrayList

```
... JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, dados, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista));
```

isso resolveu o problema.